# Given a block of text with \r and \n - Is there an online tool to unescape? make new lines etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given text like:

Welcome to the aaaa xxxx!\r\n\r\333

Is there an online tool to convert that to:

Welcome to the aaaa xxxx!

333

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just replace `"\\r\\n"` with `"\n"` (a real newline)?

Comment: Thanks but I'm curious if there is a web app available to do it. like on online form.

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/XqkzW/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have for instance php function nl2br

Comment: The question starter tagged the question as JS/HTML though.